# Where I put auto-generated classes?

Tags: java, maven, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I use cxf maven plugin to generate classes for web services. I wonder which directory I specify for `<sourceRoot>`.

Is it a good practice to put the generated classes in `${basedir}\target\classes` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an excerpt from the documentation:

> By default, the codegen plugin follows the Maven convention of
>   "target/generated-sources/cxf" for the output folder for the generated
>   classes. You can override this value using  as shown
>   below, but note this is usually not necessary,

So in other word no need to overwrite it. Just follow the conventions.